# Folium choropleth defaults to filled rather than empty

Tags: pandas, geojson, choropleth, folium

I am following this tutorial:

- https://python-graph-gallery.com/292-choropleth-map-with-folium/

I have zcta-level geojson for all of the state of New York from here:

- https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/raw/master/ny_new_york_zip_codes_geo.min.json

I am seeking to make a choropleth restricted to some values in Harlem:

```
harlem = ["10026", "10027", "10030", "10037", "10039", "10029", "10035"]

df2 = df[df.zcta.isin(harlem)]
df2['C_pct'] = df2.C/df2.C.sum()
df2.head()

    C   zcta    C_pct
89  40  10026   0.4
90  40  10027   0.4
91  20  10030   0.2
```

However, when I do this, it seems to default to coloring all zip codes not in my  dataset as if they were 100%, rather than as if they were 0%.

I can see [from related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295540/issues-with-folium-choropleth-mapping-example), I am correctly keying my "key_on" field, which in the data comes from the zcta given in: "features.properties.ZCTA5CE10"

My call is the following:

```
ny_geo = 'ny_new_york_zip_codes_geo.min.json'

m.choropleth(
    geo_data=ny_geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=df2,
    columns=['zcta', 'C_pct'],
    key_on='feature.properties.ZCTA5CE10', # this matches the geojson
    fill_color='YlGn',
    reset=True,
    legend_name='Configurations on 20170203'
)
```

And yet non-Harlem zips have color, even though there is no data for them.

[image: whygreen?]

How can I fix this?  Eg, why are Brooklyn and Queens green instead of empty?

(I [understand there to be updated syntax to geojson](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb?flush_cache=true) that eschews the choropleth function, but also wasn't able to express this in terms of the pure geojson() function--the error I had there was a key error on "id" which I was never calling, so I assume I misused a default keyword somewhere.)